# System administration rights required to edit Metadata of a Publication?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I'm using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 and the documentation states: "Users with system administration privileges can create Publications." but does that also mean that to change the Metadata on a Publication, you need to have system administration privileges?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you have a Publication Manager group that has its scope set to all publications, and has set the Publication Management right enabled.

So when you assign a user to this group he or she is able to manage the Publication's metadata. However, the default rights for this group are quite broad so you might consider trimming this down - or setting specific rights for a user or group.